# How do I check the triangle inequality using subsets?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

How do I establish the triangle inequality $|x+y| \geq |x|+|y|$ by considering all real numbers as the union of six subsets and checking the inequality on each of those subsets?

Comment: As the union of **six** subsets? Subsets of what? Also, you want $|x+y|\color{red}{\leq}|x|+|y|$.

Comment: We don't know, I dont think it matter what is in the six subsets, the inequality should always hold...

Comment: I think you mean *cases*, not *subsets*.

Comment: the worksheet says subsets, but idk what the difference is...

Comment: does anyone know how we would establish the general triangle inequality |x1+...+xn| less than or equal to |x1|+...+|xn| by repeating the application of the triangle inequality.

Comment: Use induction. ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is the set of ordered pairs $(x,y)$ that is broken up into $6$ subsets. So we are breaking up $\mathbb{R}^2$, not $\mathbb{R}$.

The easiest case is (i) both $x$ and $y$ are $\ge 0$. The next easiest is (ii) $x\le 0$, $y\le 0$ and $x$ and $y$ not both $0$, since that's already taken care of.

Now come the mixed cases where one of $x$ or $y$ is $\lt 0$ and the other is $\gt 0$.

Each breaks up into $2$ cases. For example, with $x\gt 0$, we can have (iii) $y\lt 0$ and $|y|\ge x$ or (iv) $y\lt 0$ and $|y|\lt x$.

The case $x\lt 0$ and $y\ge 0$ also breaks up into two cases, giving a total of $6$.  But we really need not worry about them, since we can take advantage of the symmetry and interchange the roles of $x$ and $y$. In view of this observation there really are only $4$ *really different* cases. (Actually, cases (ii) and (iv)$ are not greatly different from each other. The idea that deals with one adapts readily to deal with the other.)